# subtracting the hours from a total of hours granted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have difficulty in subtracting the hours worked (column B), from a total of hours granted (Column A)

A simple subtraction between the two cells does not produce the desired result, probably because the operations are done in base 10, while I would like to do them in base 60.

Here is an example:
[image]

In the example, the result had to be 14,15

What kind of formula can help me?

Comment: You understand that 3.45 hours is not the same thing as 3 hours and 45 minutes, yes? 3.45 hours is about (but not exactly) 3 hours and 27 minutes.

Comment: @mike-scott 3,45 must be considered 3 hours and 45 minutes

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Excel doesn't recognise your data as time.

*(Should 3,45 be 3 hours 45 minutes? And what is 2,2: 2 hours 2 minutes or 2 hours 20 minutes??)*

Best approach would be to fix the formatting of your data, so subtraction will work correctly:

[image]

---

### Alternate solution

If you absolutely need to use that format you might use the formulas below.
(You might manage to put them into one single formula, which will be very long).

[image]

- hour subtract: `=INT(A2)-INT(B2)`
  subtract hour parts of data
- part hour subtract: `=((A2-INT(A2))-(B2-INT(B2)))*100/60`
  subtract decimal parts (minutes) with 60 base
- part hour: `=D2+(D2<0)`
  converts previous result to positive value
- result: `=C2-(D2<0)+E2*60/100`
  calculates final result

Comment: 3,45 must be considered 3 hours and 45 minutes. 2,2 is 2 hours and 20 minutes. no, I want to use the 3,45 format. I don't want to use the 03:45 format

Comment: @nicovon: please see my update with a formula working with your desired format

Comment: what would the formula be in a single cell?

Comment: something like `=(INT(A2)-INT(B2))-((((A2-INT(A2))-(B2-INT(B2)))*100/60)<0)+((((A2-INT(A2))-(B2-INT(B2)))*100/60)+((((A2-INT(A2))-(B2-INT(B2)))*100/60)<0))*60/100`

Answer (score 2):

Formula for C1 will be =(A1-B1)/24 and format it as [h]:mm

Comment: it returns `#VALUE` error when using data provided by OP

Comment: @PeterH do you have the same international setting set?  Being from the UK like me, having the wrong setting 2,2 could be text instead of the number 2.2

Comment: I guess ,(comma) represents .(decimal) in his regional settings as its right aligned

Comment: yep wrong setting, works as expected now +1

Comment: `(18-3.45)/24` will result `14:33`, I'm not sure that's what expected based on the question ("probably because the operations are done in base 10, while I would like to do them in base 60")

Comment: @zeeshan Yes, ,(comma) represents .(decimal) in my regional settings

Comment: @nicovon You can’t have a comma represent both a decimal and an hour:minute separator, because that’s ambiguous. Pick one and stick to it, and use something else for the other one.